# unexpected removal of all documents in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

Experiencing some strange behavior of mongo in node with mongoose.
Everything points to the fact that the following code under unknown circumstances removes all documents in 'site' collection. But how can this be? Please help, spent whole day for this issue.

```
function (request, callback) {
  async.parallel({
    user:function(callback){
      User.findById(request.user_id, callback);
    },
    site:function(callback){
      Site.findById(request.site_id, callback);
    }
  }, function(err, values){
    if (err){return callback(err);}

    if (!values.user || !values.site) {
      return callback(1);
    }

    values.user.status.active = data.val;
    values.user.status.modified = new Date();

    values.site.status.active = data.val;
    values.site.modified = new Date();

    async.parallel([
      function(callback) {values.user.save(callback);},

      function(callback) {
        if (data.val) {
          values.site.save(callback);
        } else {

          // this removes all documents in collection in some unknown cases
          values.site.remove(callback);
        }
      }

    ], callback);
  });
}
```

Comment: If query criteria is not specified and justOne is not set to true, which is your case (values.site.remove(callback)), remove() removes all the documents

Comment: @Ben, but in mongoose findById method is just wrapper on mongo findOne (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), so Site.findById should return single document or null, if document with id provided is not found. And than values.site.remove calls remove method of single document (and not of collection). Or maybe I am wrong with that?

values.site here - is a result of Site.findById(request.site_id, callback);

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I overlooked values.site... you might need to set breakpoint and see what values.site is and how many document remove() removes

Comment: under dev environment all works as should be: values.site right before invoking remove method is mongoose model, values.site.toString gives exact site object as expected and remove method removes only needed document (site). But in production this  (I belive) code leads to removing all sites from collection. This is the only place with remove method used in whole server.

Comment: Log everything and review when you see it go poof.  I agree with Ben, there has to be a circumstance where you are getting back a null object and that is being passed to remove that is then converting to an empty selector and thus blowing it all away.  Also, it looks like your goal is to perform a soft delete/activate, so why call remove at all?